# Iterative Equations in Wolfram Alpha

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I am trying to solve an iterated equation, but it is quite messy and I am having trouble. Here are my equations:

$$ \mu_{t+1} = \frac{h_t \mu_t + h_\epsilon Z_t}{h_t + h_\epsilon} $$

and

$$h_{t+1} = \frac{(h_t + h_\epsilon) h_\delta}{(h_t + h_\epsilon + h_\delta)} $$

$h_0$, $m_0$, $h_\epsilon$, $h_\delta$ and $Z_t$ are all given. I would like to solve for $m_t$ in terms of the givens.

Is it possible to solve this equation in Wolfram Alpha? If not, is there a different software I could use to solve it? If both those fail, does anyone have ideas as to how I might solve it by hand? I've been struggling with it for some time, but it gets very messy very quickly!

Comment: I see no  reason to think there is a closed form.

Comment: @GEdgar, what do you mean? Shouldn't it be possible to express in terms of sums or products of the initial parameters and the $Z_t$ terms?

Comment: @GEdgar Yes there is one : see my answer.

Comment: @GEdgar It's extraordinary : I just saw your answer : we were on the same tracks !

Comment: Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be useless...
The second equation does not involve $\mu_t$ at all, so we solve only for $h_t$.  We must find the $t$ power of a certain $2 \times 2$ matrix.
Result (from Maple):
$$
h_t = \frac{A_t h_0+ B_t}{C_t h_0 + D_t}
$$
Where
$$
A_t = \left( \sqrt {h_\epsilon\, \left( 4\,h_\delta+h_\epsilon \right) }h_0+h_\epsilon\, \left( h_0-2\,h_\delta \right)  \right)  \left( {
\frac {2\,h_\delta+h_\epsilon-\sqrt {h_\epsilon\, \left( 4\,h_\delta+h_\epsilon \right) }}{h_\delta}} \right) ^{t}\\
B_t = \left( \sqrt {h_\epsilon\,
 \left( 4\,h_\delta+h_\epsilon \right) }h_0-h_\epsilon\, \left( h_0-2\,h_\delta \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {2\,h_\delta+h_\epsilon+
\sqrt {h_\epsilon\, \left( 4\,h_\delta+h_\epsilon \right) }}{h_\delta}}
 \right) ^{t}
\\
C_t =  \left( \sqrt {h_\epsilon\, \left( 4\,h_\delta+h_\epsilon \right) }-2\,h_0-h_\epsilon \right)  \left( {\frac {2\,h_\delta+h_\epsilon-\sqrt {h_\epsilon\, \left( 4\,h_\delta+h_\epsilon \right) }}{h_\delta}} \right) ^{
t}
\\D_t=
\left( \sqrt {h_\epsilon\, \left( 4\,h_\delta+h_\epsilon \right)}+2h_0+h_\epsilon \right)  \left( {\frac {2\,h_\delta+h_\epsilon+\sqrt {h_\epsilon\, \left( 4\,h_\delta+h_\epsilon \right) }}{h_\delta}}
 \right) ^{t}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Your second equation is of the form :

$$h_{n+1}=\dfrac{ah_n+b}{ch_n+d}\tag{1}$$

Therefore there is an explicit solution (see below in (2)) of $h_n$ as a fonction of $h_0$ and $n$.

Having this expression, it remains to plug it into the first equation.

Explanation for the explicit solution :

There is a formula one can find as "rational difference equation" in (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function) :

$$h_n=\frac{a}{c}+\frac {bc-ad}{c}\left[\dfrac{A\alpha^{n-1}-B\beta^{n-1}}{A\alpha^{n}-B\beta^{n}}\right]\tag{2}$$

with

$$\alpha =\dfrac {a+d+{\sqrt {(a-d)^{2}+4bc}}}{2} \ \text{and} \ \beta =\dfrac {a+d-{\sqrt {(a-d)^{2}+4bc}}}{2}$$

$$A=c \; h_0-a+\alpha \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ B=c \; h_0-a+\beta$$

**(I thought yesterday that there is a sign error in the numerator ; but this is not the case).**

**Remarks :**

1) Important : the formulas assume that $\Delta=(a-d)^2+4bc \geq 0$ which is the case for you ($\Delta=h_{\delta}^2>0$). Usually, sequence $h_n$ converges to a fixed value which is one of the roots of quadratic "fixed point" equation $H=(aH+b)/(cH+d).$

2) one can give a nice linear algebra explanation for (2) where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ upcome as eigenvalues of matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Can you confirm that, "physically" (I imagine that this issue is connected to a physical evolution as a function of dicretized time) $h_t$ is bound to be tending to a finite limit ?

Comment: Hi miss, do you know how to derive the above equation you got from wikipedia?

Comment: You can post your answer here at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4194009/iterative-functions-derivation?noredirect=1#comment8699585_4194009

Comment: I have read the article that is Link 20 from wiki, but the result is not the same as the wikipedia one